# Modify a Json file from API to suit my need

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing this quiz app using React.js which I fetch the questions from an API. Here is the first question from the JSON file I extracted from the API:

```
export default [{
"response_code": 0,
"results": [
    {

        "category": "Science: Computers",
        "type": "multiple",
        "difficulty": "medium",
        "question": "Which of these is the name for the failed key escrow device introduced by the National Security Agency in 1993?",
        "correct_answer": "Clipper Chip", //I want to copy this to the "incorrect_answers" array
        "incorrect_answers": [
            "Enigma Machine",
            "Skipjack",
            "Nautilus"
            //Clipper Chip
        ]
        // So I'll be able to have 4 buttons with options to choose from,
        // while having the "correct_answer" switch position but still retain its value
    },
    {

        "category": "Science: Computers",
        "type": "multiple",
        "difficulty": "medium",
        "question": "In the server hosting industry IaaS stands for...", ...
```

Here is what I want to do, I want to move or copy the "correct_answer" into the "incorrect_answers" array so I'll be able to have 4 options on each question when I render the JSX. Here is my code to the above:

```
data.incorrect_answers.push(data.correct_answer)
const answersElement = data.incorrect_answers.map((answer) => {
    console.log(answer)
    return (
        <>
            <button>
                {answer}
            </button>

        </>
    )
})
```

The problem with this "PUSH" method is that it duplicates the "correct_answer" buttons and doubles on each click, which is weird to me.

Remember, this data comes from an API so I can't modify it manually to suit me.
I also don't want all the correct answer options to be in the same position as all the questions, I want to be able to swap their position.

Note: I have 5 questions with 4 options on each fetch call.

Comment: Include your full React Component Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the other answers address how to merge the correct/incorrect answers I'll use my answer to address how to add the correct answer randomly to the answers array - otherwise the correct answer will always fall in the same place in the array - and also to show how verify if the clicked answer is the correct one.

```js
// Returns an integer between 0 and 3
function rnd() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
}

// Make objects from each of the array elements that
// contain the name, and a boolean value to indicate whether
// its correct or not. `splice` the correct answer randomly into
//  the array, and return it
function merge(correct, incorrect) {
  const correctObj = { name: correct, correct: true };
  const answersArr = incorrect.map(answer => {
    return { name: answer, correct: false };
  });
  answersArr.splice(rnd(), 0, correctObj);
  return answersArr;
}

function Question({ question }) {

  // Destructure the answers from the question
  const {
    correct_answer: correct,
    incorrect_answers: incorrect
  } = question;

  // Use the merge function
  const answers = merge(correct, incorrect);

  if (!answers.length) return 'No answers';

  // When you click a button find the name corresponding
  // to the correct answer, and if it matches the name in
  // the button's name data attribute log "correct" otherwise
  // "incorrect"
  function handleClick(e) {
    const { name } = answers.find(answer => answer.correct);
    if (name === e.target.dataset.name) {
      console.log('Correct');
    } else {
      console.log('Incorrect');
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{question.question}</p>
      {answers.map(answer => {
        return (
          <button
            type="button"
            data-name={answer.name}
            className="answer"
            onClick={handleClick}
          >{answer.name}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );

}

const question={category:"Science: Computers",type:"multiple",difficulty:"medium",question:"Which of these is the name for the failed key escrow device introduced by the National Security Agency in 1993?",correct_answer:"Clipper Chip",incorrect_answers:["Enigma Machine","Skipjack","Nautilus"]};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Question question={question} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.answer { padding: 0.25em 0.4em; margin: 0.25em; border-radius: 5px; }
.answer:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I check all 5 answers with a button click after the user must have made/ selected his answers. I was thinking of storing every selection in an array and then comparing it with the real correct answer array. This will allow me to show the user the correct answers with a green colour and the incorrect ones he selected in a red one the "check result" button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that:

- the JSX code is the return element or render method
- clicking the button actually does something that is not shown here (and probably change something in the Component state

The issue is that when you click (and it does something), it will re-render your component thus running the array.push once more each time. You need to "fix" your array outside of a method that runs on re-rendering. i.e. `useEffect` or wherever you actually get the API response.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry much about my onClick functions. I just need to know how to modify the output to have both the correct answer and the incorrect one on the same array. I will handle the rest from there.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const availableAnswers = [...data.incorrect_answers, data.correct_answer];
const answersElement = data.availableAnswers.map((answer) => {
    console.log(answer)
    return (
        <>
            <button>
                {answer}
            </button>

        </>
    )
})
```

Probably fixes your problem. Pushing on your response modifies it. And by the looks of it you are not fetching it again, but caching it somewhere.

Comment: Wow, such an obvious way. Thanks, let me try this out.

Comment: Probably still best that you do that outside of your JSX. Either where you fetch the data or add a property/method to where you store the data afterwards that calculates the value only once. Since you cant really scramble the order in here either or you´ll have them re-order every time you click something. Which might not make a whole lof of sence if wrong answers don´t immediately jump to the next question.

Comment: *You are right, facing the issue now. Am trying to use the useEffect hook to get the data of correct answers and incorrect to be-called ones, but it is not working. *The keeps shuffling on each click